# Strange "Undefined variable" in a JavaScript piece of code

Tags: javascript

I'm a c++ programmer so the following undefined variable error in java script is strange for me. I've defined a global variable ,`directionResult` and the following code initializes its value :

```
function calcRoute() {
    var iMap = {
        departure:"tiran,esfahan",
        destination:"esfahan"
    }
    var request = {
        origin : iMap.departure,
        destination : iMap.destination,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = result.routes[0];
            directionResult = result;
        }
    });
}
```

in the last if `directionResult` will be equal to `result` which is a parameter to a call-back function. But in another function :

```
function showSteps() {
    var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
    var point = myRoute.steps[index].start_point;
    var inst = myRoute.steps[index++].instructions;
    obj.setPosition(point);
    document.getElementById('inst').innerHTML = inst;
    map.panTo(point);
    if (index >= myRoute.steps.length)
        clearInterval(timer);
}
```

when I want to use `directionResult` at the first line,I encounter this error:

> TypeError: directionResult is undefined

How can I solve this strange behavior?thanks.

Comment: Can you put your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? There is not enough info here to say much.

Comment: Is the other function in the same JavaScript file? You might be trying to access a variable from the wrong scope.

Comment: Have you confirmed `result` isn't undefined when it is being written to `directionResult`?

Comment: My guess would be that your showSteps() function is being called before the callback passed to directionsService.route() has executed.

Comment: @Mythril Use the tilde key (the other character on it) when doing code in a comment.

Comment: What will be happened if for example if I've forgotten to define an element with 'log' id in html file.What will be happened in this line : document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = result.routes[0]; could it be the problem?Thanks friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason directionResult is undefined may be because you are trying to reference it before it has been set. Although your showSteps() function appears after the calcRoute() function, directionResult is not set until the directionsService.route() callback is fired, which happens (presumably) after an AJAX request.

Try calling showSteps() from within the directionsService.route() callback function instead.